# using an associative array to update a table using mysqli

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, mysqli

I am trying to perform an update statement using mysqli with values from a associative array. 
I can call the values I want using `$array2[0]["id"]`etc. 
So I need the statement to execute for each value in the array.

This was my last attempt at this I cant see why it is not working (my mysqli skills are very basic) :

```
$query = "update  stockistsWorld
                set     lat =  '?' and lng =  '?'   
                where   'id' =  '?' ";

        if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)){ //if connect
            foreach($array as $one){
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                $stmt ->bind_param("ssi", $one["lat"],$one["lng"],$one["id"]);
                $stmt->execute();
            }       
            $stmt->close(); 
        }
```

array is passed to this statement from the method call `addLatLng($array)` 
If i am doing this completely wrong i appologise, but in my head it looks like it should work

Comment: You only need to prepare it once.

Comment: these quotes again...

Comment: 'id'?? What about `id`?

Comment: Why are you using `$this->conn->prepare` and `$mysqli->prepare`? Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE stockistsWorld SET lat = ?, lng = ? WHERE id = ?";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){ //if connect
        foreach($array as $one){
            $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $one["lat"],$one["lng"],$one["id"]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }        
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately you failed with syntax too.